# How to resolve the link error "undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data'"

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, gcc

I'm using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) with Ubuntu Utopic and the arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler.

I've tried to compile a single program in C to read and write to a device through I2C bus but I'm getting these errors:

```
make: *** [STRME_v2] Error 1
recipe for target 'STRME_v2' failed 
undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data' 
undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data'
```

It looks more like a linker error. The functions `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data` and `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data` are defined in the `libi2c-dev`, so I installed the package `libi2c-dev`.

In my code I did:

```
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
```

I checked if the `i2c-dev.h` and `i2c.h` are in the system and I found them in `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux`

I tried several options to link the project with the library by going to `Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross GCC Linker > Libraries > Libraries (-l)` and adding `libi2c-dev`, `i2c-dev` and `i2c-core` (separately of course) but I got the same error for all: `cannot find -li2c-core`/`-llibi2c-dev`/`-li2c-dev`.

I've no idea how to make it work. I need to make it work for a graduation project.

### Response to proposed duplicate

I have written this with a more appropriate, clearer title, and a better explanation.

Comment: All you neead is to locate the libi2c*.* (.a .so, or whatever) and add the lib directory. (-L flag)

Comment: It's possible the libraries aren't installed, even though the headers are

Comment: @SHR, So, all I did to link was: Browsing to "Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross GCC Linker > Libraries" and added "libi2c-dev" in "Libraries (-l)" and added "/usr/include/linux" in "Library search path (-L)". Still not working! (headache)